# Task.Factory.StartNew does not work when run without debug mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading

This is the first time i am implementing Task.Factory.StartNew, so i dont have much idea about it. I have a function that returns a boolean value and takes a parameter. Now I have called my function using Task.Factory.StartNew.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() Myfunction(stringvalue))
```

When i am in debug mode it works and does all the operation. But when i run it without debug, it does not work. I had placed a Response.Write inside that function and it did not execute that, so it just does not enter into that function.

Below is the function that shows what am i trying to do

My Button Click event

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
 Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() Myfunction("Somevalue"))
End Sub
```

My function

```
Private Function Myfunction(ByVal str as String) as Boolean
Dim isSuccess as Boolean = False
Dim Id as Integer = SomeOtherFunction(str)
If Id > 0 Then
isSuccess =  AnotherFunction(Id)

End If
Return isSuccess
End Function
```

If i use    Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() Myfunction("Somevalue")).Start(), it works and does what the function is expected to do, but i get exception saying - "Start may not be called on a task that was already started"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: @Enigmativity Added some minimal code of what i am trying to do

Comment: Task.Factory.StartNew works just fine. Your code though doesn't await for that task to finish. By the time `Response.Write` is called, processing has *already* finished and the response sent to the browser. You should use logging to check when and how that task runs

Comment: There's no point in using such code too - ASP.NET requests are handled by separate threads already. It would make sense to use eg `async/await` to await for an already asynchronous operation like reading from the database or making an HTTP call, without blocking the request thread. `Task.Run` should be used if you need to run two or more things in parallel for the same request

Comment: As for `.Start()`, it didn't work and wasn't needed. `StartNew()` worked just fine in all cases. By calling `Start()` on an already running task though, the code caused an exception in the *request* thread, which was emitted to the client.

Comment: Finally, you can't just start a long-running background task in ASP.NET. [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) explains what's wrong. [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) explains how to do that properly

Comment: @MaxPayne999 - It's not minimal - it's less than minimal. You should post complete and minimal code. I should be able to copy, paste, and run your code and see the issue you're having.